# How to get piped input to ruby -e on command line?

Tags: ruby, bash, pipe, stdin

I'm trying to figure out how to write one liners on the bash console and pipe to ruby but I can't figure out how to get the input. This isn't working:

```
echo "My String" | ruby -e "#{STDIN.read.first.downcase}"
```

How can I get the piped input in ruby?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Ruby treats your line as a comment because it starts with a `#`.

This would work:

```
echo "My String" | ruby -e "puts gets.downcase"
```

Output:

```
my string
```

I've used [`Kernel#gets`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) instead of `STDIN.gets`:

> Returns (and assigns to $_) the next line from the list of files in ARGV (or $*), or from standard input if no files are present on the command line

If you want to process each line, you could use the `-p` flag. It's like wrapping your script in a `while gets(); ... end; puts $_`  block. Ruby reads each input line into `$_`, evaluates your script and outputs `$_` afterwards:

```
echo "Foo\nBar\nBaz" | ruby -pe '$_.downcase!'
```

Output:

```
foo
bar
baz
```

Comment: The OP's line doesn't start with `#` (comment), it starts with `#{...}` for string interpolation. The OPs line doesn't output anything because there's no `print` or `puts`. Adding a `-p` flag or using `-pe` would fix it.

Comment: Ruby evaluates `#{}`, not `"#{}"`, so it *is* a comment.

Comment: Then explain the output in my first example in my answer.

Comment: Try `echo "My String" | ruby -pe "#{just a comment}"` and you'll also see `My String` ;)

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. What's Ruby doing at that point? It's gobbling the input and outputting it still and that only occurs with `-pe`, not `-e`.

Comment: And this works too: `echo foo | ruby -pe ''`, not that it's useful. It's unexpected behavior to me, and I'd consider it almost a bug. I wonder if Matz would counter that it doesn't surprise him. :-)

Comment: It reads the input lines and prints them afterwards: *assume `while gets(); ... end` loop around your script ... but print line also like sed*. You have to alter the lines to see a difference, e.g.: `ls -1 | ruby -pe '$_.upcase!'`

Comment: Ah, good point. I stand corrected. Serves me right for answering when I'm fighting a migraine. Sigh. :-/ I think you've nailed the problem in the OPs question. Good job.

Answer (score 7):

Just

```
echo "My String" | ruby -ne 'puts $_.downcase'
```

or

```
echo "My String" | ruby -e "puts gets.downcase"
```

You get the idea.

Answer (score 7):

#### Examples:

Strip all lines from extra spaces:

```
ls | ruby -e "STDIN.each_line.to_a.map(&:strip).each(&method(:puts))"
```

Randomly colorize each line:

```
ls | ruby -e "require 'colorize'; STDIN.each_line { |l| print l.colorize(String.colors.sample) }"
```

Sort lines by length:

```
ls | ruby -e "puts STDIN.each_line.to_a.sort_by(&:size).reverse"
```

Sort files by file size:

```
ls -l | ruby -e 'STDIN.first; puts STDIN.each_line.to_a.map { |l| [l.split[4].to_i, l.split[8]] }.sort_by(&:first).reverse.map { |l| l.join("\t") }'
```

etc. etc.